# Magento add a column in sales shipment grid in Backend

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I am not able to pull the company names of the each orders in the shipment grid page.I am trying to add a Company Name column in SHIPMENT grid. I copied files from `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php`. I doubt in which table I have to join the company name in `_prepareCollection()` function or else

How can add already exist Company Name in Customer Form in SHIPMENT Grid ??

```
<?php

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_shipment_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_shipment_grid_collection';
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and set collection of grid
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and add columns to grid
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipment #'),
            'index'     => 'increment_id',
            'type'      => 'text',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_increment_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'index'     => 'order_increment_id',
            'type'      => 'text',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_created_at', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date'),
            'index'     => 'order_created_at',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('company_name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company Name'),
            'index'     => 'company_name',
            'type'      => 'text',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_qty', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Qty'),
            'index' => 'total_qty',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_shipment/view'),
                        'field'   => 'shipment_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'is_system' => true
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * Get url for row
     *
     * @param string $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/shipment')) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_shipment/view',
            array(
                'shipment_id'=> $row->getId(),
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and set options for massaction
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('shipment_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('PDF Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_shipment/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url of grid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you changed in Grid.php ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need to add an column (for company name) in your copied file and also add an extra renderer to show your desired data.

1. append the codes below to **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php**

   `$this->addColumn('company_name', array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company Name'),
       'index' => 'company_name',
       'type' => 'text',
       'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Renderer_Info'
   ));`
2. add the codes below to **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Renderer/Info.php**

   `<?php
   class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Renderer_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
   {
       public function render(Varien_Object $row)
       {
           return 'example.com';
       }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Copy core files into your local code pool
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php

Append the below code in _prepareColumns() function

```
$this->addColumn('company_name', array( 
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company Name'), 
     'index' => 'company_name', 'type' => 'text', 
     'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Renderer_Info' ));
```

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Renderer/Info.php

```
<?php

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Renderer_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row['order_id']);
    if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
        echo "-";
    }
    else {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
        $address_id = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
        if ((int)$address_id)
        {
            $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($address_id);
            echo $address->getCompany();
        }
    }
}
```

}